# How to have pages without filenames (e.g. http://localhost/site/logoff)

Tags: php, file, directory

I have a test site. I want the user to be able to logoff, but it looks ugly to go to: 'localhost/site/index.php?logoff=y'. I'm a newby at PHP, and it's probably pretty obvious how to do this, but...

How would I do this? I want the logoff link to go to 'localhost/site/logoff'
Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is usually done via mod_rewrite. Take a look at the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and for examples and a beginners page [modrewrite.com](http://www.modrewrite.com/).

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Thanks, both of you! That was really quick! I'll take a look at those.!

Answer (score 4):

The keyword you are looking for, if your site is running Apache, is `mod_rewrite`. Those are URL rewriting commands you usually place in a `.htaccess` file in your web site folder. See for example [this tutorial](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting).

The official [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is, of course, the ultimate reference but a bit harder to chew. Before starting to fiddle with mod_rewrite, make sure your provider / server has `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished in the .htaccess file with the ForceType directive.

If you created a file called "site", then put a .htaccess file in that directory

```
<Files site>
        ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Apache would treat site as if it were a php document, and requests to /site/blah would be routed to it.